# Height attribute messing with frontend visibility?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to create a list of notes on my website.

I currently have a problem where I have a gradient background color when you hover over the different note titles. This for some reason requires a height.

If I do not have this height attribute (the height attribute for .blur-container), the background won't switch colors when I hover. However, the note text is shown as expected:

Before clicking the title:
https://gyazo.com/4619429746b1de039987be48a7480917

After clicking the title:
https://gyazo.com/999277ba3939bfd875ca4562c935ac3c

If I DO have the height attribute, The background goes a little white as expected, however when I click on the title, the note text does not show.

When hovering over title:
https://gyazo.com/b70eddd96e45836296e20a21c329754a

What is the issue here and how can I fix it? I pasted my html and CSS below:

HTML:

```
<div class="task-notes-container">
  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control task-notes" placeholder="Title" (keyup)="addNotesItem($event)" [(ngModel)]="newNotesTitle"/>
  <i (click)="addNotesItem($event)" class="add-item-icon ion-plus-round"></i>
  <div class="box-shadow-border"></div>

  <ul class="notes-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getNotDeleted()" [ngClass]="{checked: item.isChecked, active: item.isActive}"
        (mouseenter)="item.isActive=true" (mouseleave)="item.isActive=false">
        <div class="blur-container" [ngClass]="{'changeHeight': item.expand}"><div class="blur-box"></div></div>
      <div class="note-title" (click)="expandItem(item);">
            <i class="mark" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': item.color }"></i>
            <label>
            <span class="cut-with-dots"><b>{{ item.title }}</b></span>
            </label>

            <i class="remove-notes ion-ios-close-empty" (click)="item.deleted = true"></i>
      </div>

      <div [hidden]="!item.expand">
        <p [hidden]="item.hide || item.text == ''" (click)="noteTextClick(item, focusable);" [innerHTML]="item.text"></p>
        <div [hidden]="!item.hide && item.text != ''">
            <textarea placeholder="haha" [(ngModel)]="item.text" (blur)="onTextBlur(item);" (focus)="onTextFocus(item);" placeholder="Default Input" class="form-control" id="textarea01" #focusable></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import '../../../theme/sass/conf/conf';

input.task-notes {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

ul.notes-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  .placeholder, .ui-sortable-placeholder {
  }
  li {
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
    padding: 12px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid $input-border;
    cursor: grab;

    div.note-title {
        height: 42px;
    }

    i.remove-notes {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0px;
      right: 12px;
      font-size: 32px;
      transition: color 0.2s;
      color: rgba($input-border, 0.5);
      visibility: hidden;
      line-height: 42px;
      &:hover {
        color: $input-border;
      }
    }
    &:hover {
      i.remove-notes {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }

    &.checked {
      .notes-text {
        color: $content-text;
      }
      &:before {
        background: $input-border !important;
      }
    }

    i.mark {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: -1px;
      left: -1px;
      height: 42px;
      min-width: 4px;
      background: $input-border;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: min-width 0.3s ease-out;
    }

    &.active {
      i.mark {
        min-width: 40px;
      }
      label.notes-checkbox > span {
        &:before {
          color: white;
          content: '\f10c';
          margin-right: 20px;
          transition: margin-right 0.1s ease-out;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
          float: none;
        }
      }
      label.notes-checkbox > input:checked + span:before {
        content: '\f00c';
      }
    }
  }
}

label.notes-checkbox {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;
  min-height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  > span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 16px;
    &:before {
      border: none;
      color: $help-text;
      transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
    }
  }
}

.add-item-icon {
  display: none;
}

.ng2, .blur {

  .task-notes-container {
    .notes-panel.panel {
      color: white;
      opacity: 0.9;
    }
    input.task-notes {
      color: white;
      width: calc(100% - 25px);
      border-radius: 0;
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
      &:focus {
        outline: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
      }
    }
    .add-item-icon {
      display: block;
      float: right;
      margin-top: -45px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      font-size: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul.notes-list {
      li {
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
        font-weight: $font-light;

        .blur-container {
          height: 40px;
          position: absolute;
          width: calc(100% + 40px);;
          top: 0;
          left: -25px;
          overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .changeHeight {
            height: auto;
        }

        &:hover {
          .blur-container {
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
          }
          .blur-box {
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 100%;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
            -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
          }
        }
        i.remove-notes {
          color: white;
          opacity: 0.4;
          &:hover {
            color: white;
            opacity: 0.95;
          }
        }
        i.mark {
          min-width: 40px;
          display: none;
        }
        label.notes-checkbox > span {
          &:before {
            position: absolute;
            color: $content-text;
            content: '\f10c';
            float: none;
            margin-right: 6px;
            transition: none;
          }
        }
        &.checked {
          label.notes-checkbox > span {
            &:before {
              content: '\f00c';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .box-shadow-border {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
      width: calc(100% + 44px);
      margin-left: -22px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not HTML, that is some kind of templating language. Please show the actual HTML, and a live example.

Comment: It is HTML. It's just Angular 2 framework. If you remove the angular components, the html and css works the same way without the extra functionality.